# assigning values to `*x` through the C Interface of Julia

Tags: c, interface, julia

I would like to `translate` the following C function:

```
static void my_C_func(int *x) {
    *x = 100;
    return;
}
```

into a Julia function. Perhaps:

```
function my_julia_func(x::Ptr{Cint})
     *x = 100
     return
end
```

In `my_julia_func`, the line with `*x = 100` does not work, of course. What should I do with that line?

Just for more information, `my_C_func` is a callback function in C, and I'm trying to create a Julia wrapper for callback.

**UPDATE**
It seems like `Ptr(x)=100`. I tested two pointer arguments:

```
function my_julia_func(x::Ptr{Cint}, y::Ptr{Cint})
     Ptr(x) = 100
     Ptr(y) = 200
     println("*x = ", Ptr(x))
     println("*y = ", Ptr(y))
end
```

The result is

```
*x = 200
*y = 200
```

Seems strange. If I do :

```
function my_julia_func(x::Ptr{Cint}, y::Ptr{Cint})
     Ptr(x) = 100
     println("*x = ", Ptr(x))
     Ptr(y) = 200
     println("*y = ", Ptr(y))
end
```

I obtain:

```
*x = 100
*y = 200
```

How should I correctly do this?

When I just printed `x` and `y`, it shows:

```
x = Ptr{Int32} @0x00007fff5d57685c
y = Ptr{Int32} @0x00007fff5d576858
```

Comment: That's not a valid C function.

Comment: @Lundin LOL... You see I'm certainly not good at C... Is it fine now?

Comment: Yes now it is correct, although the `return ;` is not needed.

Comment: Why do you want to do this at all? Julia is not C. What is it that you are actually trying to do?

Comment: @DavidP.Sanders I'm trying to write a Julia wrapper for an existing C library. Trying to translate its interface...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Ptr(x) = 100` defines a local function, shadowing the global definition of `Ptr`. That's not what you want at all, and that's why defining `Ptr(y) = 200` changed the value of `Ptr(x)`. `Ptr` does not dereference pointers anyway, so this is not the correct function.

You want:

```
function my_julia_func!(x::Ptr{Cint})
     unsafe_store!(x, 100)
     nothing
end
```

(with the `nothing` serving similar purpose to your `return`, but a bit more idiomatic)

Similarly, to "dereference" `x`, you want `unsafe_load(x)`. Note that these operations are `unsafe`, so you ensure that you know what you are doing before doing them, or you risk a segmentation fault or memory corruption. (Though they are not any more unsafe than C's pointer dereference.)